Windows move to the foreground when clicking on other application window
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04.1. Everything looks great but I'm struggling with the following behavior:
Let's say I have two browser windows on the left half of the screen, one on top of the other one, and a window of another application on the right half of the screen. When I click on the application window on the right, and the left half of the screen is showing the second browser window (the window opened later), the left half of the screen switches to the first browser window.
Obviously, this is quite annoying if I need to do something with the application on the right-hand side while looking at the second browser window because it goes to the background whenever I click on the application on the right...
I'm assuming this behavior can be configured somehow but I couldn't figure out what configuration I need to change. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This seems like bug that I can't reproduce. Try to disable all window management extensions.

Thanks for the tip! I actually installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 on two different machines (HP Elitebook and Lenovo Carbon X1) and I get the same behavior on both machines, and I didn't install any extensions...
Are there any specific settings that I should look into? Are maybe try out some extensions?

I think I figured it out:
In the GNOME extension manager (apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager), I checked the settings of the "Ubuntu Tiling Assistant" (by clicking on the cogwheel icon) and then I disabled "Tile Groups > Raise together".
Now the behavior mentioned above is gone.

Please click the gray check beside your answer to mark it as accepted. Clicking the check makes it change color from gray to green.
